# Derivative of eigenvalue equation dependent on vector parameters

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, matrix-equations

For an eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ we have $Av=\lambda v$. Assume that both $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ depend on $n$ parameters represented as a vector $p=[p1,p2,\dots,p_n]$. I want to know how the eigenvalue $\lambda$ changes with respect to $p$, but I am not sure if I am differentiating $A(p)v(p) = \lambda(p) v(p)$ correctly.

Let $y = A(p)v(p)$ and $z = \lambda(p)v(p)$. Then,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial p} &= \frac{\partial y}{\partial p}
\\[1em] \frac{\partial y}{\partial A} \frac{\partial A}{\partial p} v + A \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p} v + \lambda \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\\[1em]
\frac{\partial A}{\partial p}(v,v) + A^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} 
 &= \bigg(v^T \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p}\bigg) v + \lambda^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} 
\end{align}

Premultiplying both sides by the left eigenvector $w^T$ (i.e., $w^TA=w^T\lambda)$, and using $w^Tv=1$ to simplify, I get

$$
\begin{align}
w^T \frac{\partial A}{\partial p}(v,v)
 &= v^T \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p}
\end{align}
$$

I am just not sure about the step where I go from $\frac{\partial y}{\partial A} \frac{\partial A}{\partial p} v = \frac{\partial A}{\partial p}(v,v)$ since $\frac{\partial A}{\partial p}$ is a third order tensor.

Comment: I don't suppose we can assume $A$ is a normal matrix.

Comment: No, sadly $A$ is not normal.

Comment: Can we assume it is diagonalizable for all $p$?

Comment: I am not sure that would be true. But please go ahead and make the assumption if that helps out!

Comment: I don't understand your parameter(s) $p_k$ : why would you need the same number of parameters as the dimension $n$ of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? Besides, what is $p$ in your computation : a scalar parameter or a vector parameter ?

Comment: This is a problem that I encountered as par of a larger problem that I am looking into for my research. Every entry in $A$ might depend on one of $n$ parameters $p_k$. I am differentiating with respect to the vector $p = [p_1,\dots,p_n]$.

Comment: 1) You can be interested by the following document : https://www.win.tue.nl/casa/meetings/seminar/previous/_abstract051019_files/Presentation.pdf 2)  I wasn't aware of your answer because you hadn't begin it with my pseudo 3)  Why do you work at once with $n$ parameters instead of differentiating with respect to a single one at first ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the link. I was aware of the equation for the single parameter case. I am interested in the $n$ parameters case because this equation pops up as a transversality condition for bifurcations in higher dimensional system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this fairly easily just by differentiating the eigenvalue equation $Av = \lambda v$,
$$
A' v + A v' = \lambda' v + \lambda v'
$$
Now multiply through on the left by $w^T$, where $w$ is the left eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ (that is, $w^TA = \lambda w^T$, and also $w^Tv = 1$). Then we have
$$
w^TA'v + \lambda w^Tv' = \lambda'w^T v + \lambda w^T v' \Longrightarrow \lambda' = w^T A' v
$$
If you have multiple parameters, then for each parameter $p$, 
$$
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial p} = w^T\frac{\partial A}{\partial p} v
$$
If you've done quantum mechanics before, you'll recognize this as essentially [time-independent perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-independent_perturbation_theory).

---

Now, there's an important thing to watch out for here. Consider the derivative of the $i$th eigenvector $v'_i$. An abbreviated derivation of the expression for it is
\begin{multline}
A' v_i + A v_i' = \lambda_i' v_i + \lambda_i v_i'\Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n v_kw_k^TA' v_i + A v_i' =  v_iw_i^T A' v_i + \lambda_i v_i'\\\Longrightarrow (A-\lambda_i)v_i' = \sum_{k\ne i}^n v_kw_k^TA' v_i \Longrightarrow \sum_{k\ne i}^n(\lambda_k-\lambda_i) v_kw_k^Tv_i' = \sum_{k\ne i}^n v_kw_k^TA' v_i\\\Longrightarrow v_i' =  \sum_{k\ne i}^n v_k\frac{w_k^TA' v_i}{\lambda_k-\lambda_i} + c_iv_i,
\end{multline}
where $c_i$ is determined by the normalization condition $v_i^Tv'_i = 0$. This expression can blow up if the matrix becomes defective, meaning your eigenvectors might change suddenly. This is why $A$ being normal would be very helpful--normal matrices are never defective.

Comment: [+1] I stress the fact that you differentiate with respect to a single scalar parameter, not to a vector of parameters as the OP has done.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you. I have accepted your answer. From the single parameter case, I can get the equation for the n parameter case and see that my original derivation is correct.